# Backup recovery with dd on SM-G800F

Tags: root-access, partitions

How can I backup my Recovery image with the dd command? I have the PIT file, where recovery is listed as:

```
--- Entry #12 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 10
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 129024
Partition Block Count: 24576
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: RECOVERY
Flash Filename: recovery.img
FOTA Filename:
```

What /dev/ file should I choose as my if?

When I `cat /proc/partitions`, I get some `mmcblkXpXX`, and `mmcblkXbootX`.

Since the identifier is **10**, wouldn't the if be `mmcblk0p10`?

Comment: There are many pointers in both question and answers here: [How to list all major partitions with their labels?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/92565) See if it helps.

Comment: @Firelord I found RECOVERY in the **by-name** directory. Now, to backup, do I use it in the dd command?

Answer (score 0):

According to files in the `/dev/block/platform/*/by-name` directory, my Recovery partition is in fact `/dev/block/mmcblk0p10`. The ending of the name of **mmcblk0pX** matches all the identifiers on the PIT, so thus I conclude that the identifier and the mmcblk name does match.

The command now will be `dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p10 of=/storage/sdcard1/twrp.img bs=4096`

Comment: Match the identifier in the PIT file for other partitions with the info you gathered from by-name directory. You can come to know if it is a coincidence or something else.

Comment: @Firelord that is a logical way of doing it. I am  going to do so now