# Listing partitions names and mount points

Tags: partitions

I'm trying to get list of partitions and their mount points in terminal, but I'm not so succesfull.

`"ls -l /dev/block/platform/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.msdc0/by-name/”` (found this path by using `"cat /proc/mounts"` but it return me a 'permission denied, I guess I need root, but I don't have one.
So how to get partitions names and mount points without root?
Also there is one weird thing: when I go with Total commander in /dev folder there isn't /block folder inside just file named 'block' with size 0 and not readable (becase lack of root). How is that possible?

Comment: You need to be rooted.

Comment: No way without root? Ok. Do you know anything about not existing /block folder?

Comment: It exists, you just can't properly enumerate the contents of `/dev/` without root.  I get "Permission denied" when running `ls /dev`, guessing your kernel/filesystem just behaves slightly differently.

Comment: Please see: [How to list all major partitions with their labels?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/92565/16575)

Comment: @Izzy the thing is I lack the root. That is a problem, other commands from link doesn't return me anything or says command not found.

Comment: Yeah, see above what Matthew wrote, right? Without root the best you get are "pieces of the puzzle", but not the "complete picture".

Comment: Related: [ANDROID DEVICE PARTITIONS and FILESYSTEMS](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/info-android-device-partitions-basic-t3586565)

Answer (score 0):

Type in `mount` to a terminal emulator, root not required.

Lists all mount points active, note: mine is very long due to many bind mounts.

Imgur: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuFMJ.jpg

Or alternatively

Type `grep /etc/recovery.fstab`

Comment: It doesn't give me the boot and recovery partitions.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје trying grepping /etc/recovery.fstab

Comment: https://m31i.imgup.net/Capture_204973.png

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: It doesn't show mount point for them, that's the problem

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје boot is mounted to / and recovery isn't mounted when booted.

Comment: `boot` and `recovery` are raw partitions, they don't have a mountable filesystem. Both contain kernel binary and ramdisk at fixed offsets and a header according to the format standardized by Google. On non-SAR devices `ramdisk` is mounted at `/`.