# Fail when pull system files in twrp recovery

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, twrp

My phone is Xiaomi Redmi Note 5, bootloader is already unlocked, haven't rooted yet. I boot to TWRP with the command `fastboot boot twrp-3.2.3-0-whyred.img`. Then

```
.\adb remount
.\adb pull /system/fonts
```

but it said `adb: error: failed to stat remote object '/system/fonts': No such file or directory`

I also can't list `/system` folder in `adb shell`:

```
.\adb shell
~ # ls /system
(output nothing)

~ # mount -o remount,rw /system
mount: can't find /system in /proc/mounts
```

[image: Original screenshot of the terminal output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TWRP automatically does not mount system partition. It has to be mounted manually via its UI (under Mount option) or via command line. The fact that `ls /system` showed you nothing gives us the evidence that the partition indeed is not mounted. It can further be confirmed using `mount` command.

If you must insist on mounting system partition using command line, you must get the block device ID for that partition first. There are myriad ways to do that and some are listed [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/102551/96277) by Izzy. I think the easiest may be the command `blkid` as mentioned [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/93678/96277) by Ryan. In my device it outputs:

```
~ # blkid
/dev/block/mmcblk0p42: UUID="57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/block/mmcblk0p41: LABEL="system" UUID="da594c53-9beb-f85c-85c5-cedf76546f7a" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/block/mmcblk0p38: UUID="57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/block/mmcblk0p26: UUID="57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/block/mmcblk0p21: LABEL="FSG" UUID="e4a4f807-109f-5459-8138-e744bc88c397" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/block/mmcblk0p1: LABEL="NONHLOS" UUID="75d3199b-b965-b45f-9298-59c724d8a58d" TYPE="ext4"
```

Once you have the block device ID and the filesystem type (ext4 default) you issue the command:

```
mount -t ext4 BLOCK_DEV_ID MOUNT_POINT
mount -t ext4 /dev/block/mmcblkop41 /system   # this is as an example only
```

You can now pull the files.