# Why is there NO files in TWRP recovery in adb?

Tags: adb, twrp

Without TWRP, adb devices shows no device connected.  "fastboot devices" also produces nothing in Samsung Galaxy.
But in TWRP recovery, "adb devices" show "52034c5afabcc377  recovery".

adb shell ls at root shows directories.  But adb shell cd /system and adb shell ls shows **no files**.

Question:  why devices in recovery in TWRP fail to list files?

Comment: usage hint: type `adb shell` only once

Answer (score 1):

When you only see empty directories, it is probably because the system partition is not mounted yet.

Mount `/system` either using twrp (I don't know exactly, but there is somewhere an option to mount system, maybe under settings or advanced) or using adb shell: `mount /system`

Same applies to `/data`: if it's empty too, use `mount /data`

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/201050/fail-when-pull-system-files-in-twrp-recovery?rq=1 is related and shows more information on mounting `/system`